# Jenkins: Docker plugin, "All nodes of label [...] are offline"

Tags: ssh, docker, jenkins

I got a Photon OS server running, where I'd like to create and use containers as jenkins nodes (Docker plugin). During the job I get "All nodes of label [...] are offline" although multiple containers are created and later deleted.

Since the docker API is working(connecting via tcp) and none of the current issues fits the problem I suspect that there is a problem with the setup.

I tried both jenkins/ssh-slave and jenkins/jnlp-slave as docker image.
Trying to connect to ssh-slave manually gives "ERROR: Server rejected the 1 private key(s) for root (credentialId:InstanceIdentity/method:publickey) "

I also tried opening ports on the system with `iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --match multiport --dports 32820:32860`

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance